# What makes Kleenex Cool Touch tissues cool to the touch, and is it safe?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, safety

I love Kleenex Cool Touch tissues.  I'm just wondering what makes them actually feel cool.  For some reason it makes me think of refrigerant but I'm sure that's not in them.

Is it the combination of common ingredients that somehow gives it a moist feel, making it feel cooler than normal tissues?

Are the tissues safe to put to your face, if you are potentially inhaling the ingredient(s)?

Ingredients:  Stearyl heptanoate, stearyl alcohol, polyethylene, mineral oil, coconut oil, aloe

Comment: It's definitely safe, yes. All of the ingredients you've listed above are non-toxic. Aloe verra is often used to cool burning areas (though it's treatment is questionable).

Comment: Stearyl alcohol make it cool to touch. Because alcohol evaporates easily. It is safe to use.

Comment: @lambda23: It makes sense that evaporation would make the cool-to-touch feeling, but by that logic, by the next day all of the alcohol would be gone. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: @lambda23: Maybe body heat warms up the stearyl alcohol which is what causes it to evaporate. I don't have access to a Cool Touch tissue right now, but maybe the OP does. OP: Try touching the whole tissue for so long that it's not cold anymore. Then come back and do it again. And again. And again. See if it ever stops feeling cold.

Comment: @Nile: Yes, body warms the stearyl alcohol and it will evaporate.

Comment: @lambda23 - Consult the [liquid range of stearyl alcohol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stearyl_alcohol) and you will find it is a solid at room temperature and has a boiling point of 210 C. Not the best candidate for evaporative cooling...

Comment: @RichardTerrett At the wikipedia site, the boiling point of the stearyl alcohol is 210 C at 15 mmHg. The pressure isn't n the standard state (760 mmHg).

Comment: @lambda23 - Well spotted - I missed that entirely. However it lends further support to my point that a liquid that boils at 210 C at a pressure not much higher than Mars' atmosphere is fairly nonvolatile. It's virtually wax.

Comment: @lambda23 - a bit of googling around suggests that the ingredient might be 'proprietary' and unlisted (I'm not sure how the laws work). Nothing solid though. If indeed there are extra ingredients it could be something that creates a mere sensation of coolness, similar to menthol.

Comment: @Nile: tried repeatedly touching and rubbing the tissue several times over the past few days.  It doesn't seem to be losing any coolness.  Even my wife confirmed it.  I'll try a bit more but it looks like whatever it is, it's not evaporating.  Seems more likely to be something that is quick to absorb heat.

Comment: @trpt4him It probably absorbs moisture in the air and evaporates when you begin to transfer energy

Comment: I had one of the cool touch Kleenex for a week and no matter how much I touched it after awhile I went to touch it again and it was still cold.

Comment: I thought they contained menthol or something like it. This doesn't work by affecting heat transfer but by altering the heat sensitive cells in the skin (it's the opposite effect to chilli).

Comment: Don't guess, don't read advertising. Look it up in the primary literature. US patents 7879191; 7879190; 7879189; 7879188; 7883604; 7837831; 7807023; 7820010; 5415320.

Comment: @trpt4him Volatile liquids don't all evaporate if you leave them out. You can keep a bottle of hand sanitizer out and it still has that chilling effect. Repeatedly touching would eventually get rid of the liquid, though.

Comment: Uncle Al gave a very good hint, and Leonardo came close, but then gets lost in things like metal heat conductivity, which he does not understand. The answer is simply: heat of melting! Its the same as some choolates with a high content of hardened cocos fat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first guess as to the nature of this behaviour is similar to water. Hypothermia is a realistic risk if you are drenched in water. This is because water can absorb large amounts of energy (it has a large specific heat capacity) to only rise in temperature slightly. Water itself evaporates into steam spontaneously, if some water is spilled then it will evaporate readily, regardless of the temperature. Likewise, the solids in the tissue are probably coming closer to melting temperature, which I believe is higher than your body temperature, but quickly absorbing a lot of energy from your body in the process.

Something similar to properties of water are probably characteristic to the tissue. Leave the tissue in the open in a cool room, along with a glass of water. After awhile, touching the glass of water and the tissue should invoke the same sense of coolness. This is because your body is at a higher temperature than the items in the room.

There is likely another property of matter besides specific heat capacity that is a measurement of how **quickly** heat is transferred, this is likely to play a role as well. I do not know what this property is called and it was never covered in my classes so far, but take metal for example. Metal has a very small specific heat capacity, it can not hold much energy. However, touching a metal object invokes a sense of coolness. I believe this is because heat is transferred very quickly through metal, although it warms very quickly due to its limited heat capacity. If you put a metal cup and a porcelain cup on the stove, the metal will burn you much quicker if you grab it than grabbing the porcelain/ceramic cup.

If you were very interested and inquistive you could test the specific heat of the tissue through experimentation. Also, try holding the napkin for a few seconds to try and find out how **quickly** the tissue warms to the touch. Chances are, it warms relatively fast and can absorb a lot of energy, giving you the impression that it is 'cooler' than most objects, to which marketers will be overwrought with the joy of hearing.

Comment: Saying "how quickly heat is transferred" is incorrect. Heat is the transfer of energy.

Comment: @Nile http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer "Heat ...and is synonymous with heat flow and heat transfer.

Comment: @sencer Reading the heat wikipedia page, "Heat ... is synonymous with heat flow and heat transfer." Sorry, I stand corrected.

Comment: @sencer: I see you've updated your post. Just as an FYI, it doesn't say that on the link you've sent. It says that on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat

Comment: @Nile yes, sorry. It doesn't let me fix it.

Comment: @Nile Semantics is nothing to worry about, as long as the person asking the question does not get confused. Conventionally we might describe it as $\Delta H$

Comment: Yes, it does warm quickly, but your first, immediate, impression is that it is considerably cooler than your hands.

Comment: @trpt4him Thats because it probably is a lot colder than your hands. If it is ever really hot outside, like hotter than 100 degrees Fahrenheit, your Kleenex will likely fail to impress you if my answer is at all correct. It probably only feels cold because entropy saps the heat from you but quickly matches its surroundings.

Answer (score -3):

Here is the answer, but I don't understand it.

http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=2&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=86&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=%22kimberly+clark%22&OS=%22kimberly+clark%22&RS=%22kimberly+clark%22

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.